# c# detect application focused lost focus

Tags: c#

I seem to have a problem I am trying to detect when my form loses focus but it has a COM interop based user control on it to display a web cam feed. This is causing the loses and gained focus events to not always fire. Is there a way to detect that the application has lost focus, perhaps through a windows api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466354/how-can-i-tell-if-a-window-has-focus-win32-api) might help you.

Comment: I got the handles to all my forms and used them in my Activated and Deactivaterd event handlers on the forms. This allowed me to detect none of the applications forms are active.