# WinForms: How to determine if window is no longer active (no child window has focus)?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, user32

My application uses multiple windows

I want to hide one specific window in case the application loses focus (when the Active Window is not the application window) [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466354/how-can-i-tell-if-a-window-has-focus-win32-api/466372#466372)

I am handling the `Deactivate` event of my main form.

```
    private void MainForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("deactivate");
      if (GetActiveWindow() == this.Handle) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine("isactive=true");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("isactive=false");
      }
    }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
```

The output is always

```
deactivate
isactive=true
```

I have observed the same behavior if a new window within my application receives focus and also if I click into a different application.

I would expect `GetActiveWindow` to return the handle of the new active window when called from the `Deactivate` handler. Instead it always returns the handle of my application window.

How is this possible? Is the Deactivate event handled "too soon"? (while the main form is still active?).

How can I detect that my application has lost focus (my application window is not the active window) and another application gained it without running GetActiveWindow on a timer?

Comment: Are we talking about an MDI application?

Comment: no, this is not an MDI application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see GetActiveWindow get's the active window for the calling thread, i.e. your app so it's always going to return the current window of your app. I think perhaps you are looking for GetForegroundWindow which will return the handle to the window the user currently has active.

Comment: Good point. Be aware, by the way, that `GetForegroundWindow` may return NULL in some situations (e.g. switching focus by clicking a taskbar button).

Comment: @Thomas, good programming practice to check for NULL even if you don't expect it but good to highlight it (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm observing the same behaviour (.NET 3.5, Visual Studio 2008). The documentation is hazy:

> Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.

However, the contrast between the event names (Activate**d** versus Deactivate) suggests that the event does indeed come before the actual deactivation.