# C#, how to detect new application being open?

Tags: c#, dll

I am using a library ( *.dll ) that keeps popping out a window ( which appears as an application in the task manager ) , like "are you sure?..." Yes/No when a certain function is executed.

Is there some way to automatically detect this window/form/application being opened and to close it?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually programs ask for confirmation when you're about to do something destructive. Why would you want to stop that check?

Comment: @Ken White:  Probably to workaround the fact that the OP has a DLL that decided in should show popup windows, which is likely not a good idea.

Comment: since I know what I want to program to do and, moreover, since I'm doing it in a loop, its bugging me when I have to keep pressing 'yes' all the time, until it goes though the loop. :) so I want to somehow be able to detect this window appearing ( it appears in TaksManager/Applications , btw ) and automatically hit 'yes'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`button.performclick` -
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx

Comment: Dialog != Form. I have a hunch we're dealing with the former here.

Comment: Yes, we're dealing with a new form, now a dialogue. :)

Comment: @Kumar: If that were possible, it would seem the _work around_ would be to use no window at all.

Comment: yea thats right, but according to poster he says he knows what he is coding for, not sure what is the problem situation he dealing with.

Comment: the problem is that a library .dll keeps popping a window, that I need to somehow get automatically closed.

Comment: look into this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517295/winforms-how-to-determine-if-window-is-no-longer-active-no-child-window-has-foc

Comment: -1 `button.performClick` works fine if it's in your own application, where you have access to 'button' directly. You don't have in a DLL, though, so this won't work (if the OP had direct access to `button', there wouldn't be a need to ask this question).