# Hooked keyboard duplicating input (c# / xna)

Tags: c#, forms, keyboard, xna, hook

I'm using a Keyboard hook in my XNA project (anyone who uses XNA knows how useless the built in keyboard class is for "text box" style typed input.

It works just fine for use in XNA projects, until forms are introduced. If I try to implement any form in the project, be it a custom form, or even just an OpenFileDialog, any key press inside a text box of the form is doubled, making typing just about impossible.

Does anyone know how I can stop the message from reaching the forms twice? perhaps by discarding the message when I get it? Perhaps there is a better solution? or perhaps its just something that cant be done.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Below is the keyboard hooking code I'm using, It may be familiar to anyone who's gone looking for XNA keyboard hooking as it seems to crop up wherever I looked for it.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms; // This class exposes WinForms-style key events.

namespace FatLib.Controls
{
    class KeyboardHookInput : IDisposable
    {
        private string _buffer = "";
        private bool _backSpace = false;
        private bool _enterKey = false; // I added this to the original code

        public string Buffer
        {
            get { return _buffer; }
        }
        public bool BackSpace
        {
            get
            {
                return _backSpace;
            }
        }
        public bool EnterKey
        {
            get
            {
                return _enterKey;
            }
        }
        public void Reset()
        {
            _buffer = "";
            _backSpace = false;
            _enterKey = false;
        }

        public enum HookId
        {
            // Types of hook that can be installed using the SetWindwsHookEx function.
            WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
            WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
            WH_CBT = 5,
            WH_DEBUG = 9,
            WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
            WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
            WH_HARDWARE = 8,
            WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
            WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
            WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
            WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
            WH_MAX = 11,
            WH_MAXHOOK = WH_MAX,
            WH_MIN = -1,
            WH_MINHOOK = WH_MIN,
            WH_MOUSE_LL = 14,
            WH_MSGFILTER = -1,
            WH_SHELL = 10,
            WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
        };
        public enum WindowMessage
        {
            // Window message types.
            WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100,
            WM_KEYUP = 0x101,
            WM_CHAR = 0x102,
        };

        // A delegate used to create a hook callback.
        public delegate int GetMsgProc(int nCode, int wParam, ref Message msg);

        /// <summary>
        /// Install an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">Specifies the type of hook procedure to be installed.</param>
        /// <param name="lpfn">Pointer to the hook procedure.</param>
        /// <param name="hmod">Handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the lpfn parameter.</param>
        /// <param name="dwThreadId">Specifies the identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated.</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle to the hook procedure. Otherwise returns 0.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookExA")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookId idHook, GetMsgProc lpfn, IntPtr hmod, int dwThreadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes a hook procedure installed in a hook chain by the SetWindowsHookEx function. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHook">Handle to the hook to be removed. This parameter is a hook handle obtained by a previous call to SetWindowsHookEx.</param>
        /// <returns>If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

        /// <summary>
        /// Passes the hook information to the next hook procedure in the current hook chain.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHook">Ignored.</param>
        /// <param name="ncode">Specifies the hook code passed to the current hook procedure.</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">Specifies the wParam value passed to the current hook procedure.</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">Specifies the lParam value passed to the current hook procedure.</param>
        /// <returns>This value is returned by the next hook procedure in the chain.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int hHook, int ncode, int wParam, ref Message lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// Translates virtual-key messages into character messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpMsg">Pointer to an Message structure that contains message information retrieved from the calling thread's message queue.</param>
        /// <returns>If the message is translated (that is, a character message is posted to the thread's message queue), the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool TranslateMessage(ref Message lpMsg);


        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the thread identifier of the calling thread.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The thread identifier of the calling thread.</returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

        // Handle for the created hook.
        private readonly IntPtr HookHandle;

        private readonly GetMsgProc ProcessMessagesCallback;

        public KeyboardHookInput()
        {
            // Create the delegate callback:
            this.ProcessMessagesCallback = new GetMsgProc(ProcessMessages);
            // Create the keyboard hook:
            this.HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(HookId.WH_KEYBOARD, this.ProcessMessagesCallback, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Remove the hook.
            if (HookHandle != IntPtr.Zero) UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookHandle);
        }

        // comments found in this region are all from the original author: Darg.
        private int ProcessMessages(int nCode, int wParam, ref Message msg)
        {
            // Check if we must process this message (and whether it has been retrieved via GetMessage):
            if (nCode == 0 && wParam == 1)
            {
                // We need character input, so use TranslateMessage to generate WM_CHAR messages.
                TranslateMessage(ref msg);

                // If it's one of the keyboard-related messages, raise an event for it:
                switch ((WindowMessage)msg.Msg)
                {
                    case WindowMessage.WM_CHAR:
                        this.OnKeyPress(new KeyPressEventArgs((char)msg.WParam));
                        break;
                    case WindowMessage.WM_KEYDOWN:
                        this.OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs((Keys)msg.WParam));
                        break;
                    case WindowMessage.WM_KEYUP:
                        this.OnKeyUp(new KeyEventArgs((Keys)msg.WParam));
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Call next hook in chain:
            return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, ref msg);
        }

        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
        protected virtual void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (KeyUp != null) KeyUp(this, e);
        }

        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
        protected virtual void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (KeyDown != null) KeyDown(this, e);
        }

        public event KeyPressEventHandler KeyPress;
        protected virtual void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (KeyPress != null) KeyPress(this, e);
            if (e.KeyChar.GetHashCode().ToString() == "524296")
            {
                _backSpace = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                _enterKey = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _buffer += e.KeyChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a project with multiple forms, it'd make sense for it to be a windows forms project, in which case can't you just handle keydown?

Comment: codes added. The problem is this keyboard hook is intended to be part of a games library, so there's no telling if multiple forms will be used, if any forms at all.

Comment: There has to be a form, since XNA's `GraphicsDevice` needs something to draw on. I'd suggest providing a method for the user of your class library to provide the handle of the form, or maybe Form object its self, then before calling onkeypress etc. check if it has focus.

Comment: of course! I'll give that a go and see how it pans out.

Comment: Works like a charm. Fantastic, much appreciate George, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Windows Hook is a pretty nasty way of getting at all the keypresses, and should be an absolute last resort.

Try installing a [Message Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) into your application, which can watch for all the keyboard messages that are sent to your application (WM_KEYPRESS, KEYUP, KEYDOWN, etc) without interfering with other applications. A filter will also allow you to stop any messages reaching any forms in your application if you wish.

Comment: +1, didn't know about this; if it works in XNA (can't test on this PC) i'd say this is the preferred solution.

Comment: Will a message filter interfere with the existing XNA keyboard class? I know I'm being messy by still using the keyboard class as well as the keyboard hook, but for the time being my keyboard hook is only used for "as typed" input, not general checks for individual keys (which still relies on the XNA keyboard class)

Comment: The XNA keyboard class tells you if a key is pressed at that moment in time. Keyboard hooks, and jason's method deals with windows messages, and so is unrelated.

Comment: Well then I shall look into Message filters then, see if I can't tidy up my inputs a bit. Many thanks to both of you.

Comment: Here's an example of a class that uses this method: http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2011/06/key-events-in-xna-40.html

Comment: This seems like a much cleaner way of doing it, and as it seems to work fine in my test application I think I'll use it. :) thanks again guys.

Answer (score 3):

Since there has to be a form in XNA (the `GraphicsDevice` requires it) you're going to have 2 options depending on whether the user of your library creates the form ([winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) project with XNA for rendering), or whether the form is created as a result of creating a normal XNA game.

In the [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) case, you can just handle the key events, job done.

In the standard XNA game case, you can get the user to pass the handle of the window that the graphics device created, then before calling your `OnKey...` methods, check that the window has focus.

You could go with the 2nd option in both cases to make it simpler. The user of your library would pass in the handle of the window to receive/buffer key presses in the constructor of `KeyboardHookInput`. Then you'd check that the window has focus first (see here: [How can I tell if a Window has focus? (Win32 API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466354/how-can-i-tell-if-a-window-has-focus-win32-api)).

Comment: Thanks George, I've used the focus trick before to ignore mouse clicks, no idea why it didn't occur to me to try it with the keyboard hook. Suffice to say, it works like a charm, and has now been built in  to my core. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You might like to look into @Jason's answer too as if it works i'd say it's a better alternative. Once you've commited to a solution be sure to accept that answer (click the green tick). If the other answer also helped you, you can 'upvote' it (click the grey up arrow/triangle).