# Where in Win32 C++ code to place SetMenuItemInfo() to enable/disable based on focus?

Tags: c++, winapi, menuitem, paste

I'm writing a C++ application for Win32 in VS 2010 Pro. The app contains an **Edit** menu with a **Paste** item, and the app's main window contains a text box control. All of the routine Cut/Copy/Paste commands are working nicely in that control -- which happens to be the application's only user-editable field.

I want to disable the **Paste** menu item when there is no cursor blinking in the text box control -- that is, when the text box does not have the focus -- because when the text box is not the "active" control, no Cut/Copy/Paste action is possible.

I can enable/disable the menu item using the following code (as I've tested by placing this snippet right after the menu is created, inside WM_CREATE -- as a test). I don't know where to place the code in my program so that it's called in the course of normal user events -- like mouse clicks -- that would take the focus away from/return it to the text box.

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
mii.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_EDIT_PASTE, FALSE, &mii);
mii.fState ^= MFS_DISABLED;
SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_EDIT_PASTE, FALSE, &mii);
```

Once the code is placed in the correct location, I plan to embed it in an **if** statement so that it runs (disabling the menu item) only if the app's text box does not have the focus:

```
if(GetFocus() != hWndTextbox)
```

Perhaps there is a **case** statement inside my **CALLBACK switch(msg)** section where this should all reside? I'm still learning basic C++ Win32 program structure. Thank you!

(PS two resources that have helped me get this far: [An examination of menus from a beginner's point of view](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7503/An-examination-of-menus-from-a-beginner-s-point-of), [How can I tell if a Window has focus? (Win32 API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466354/how-can-i-tell-if-a-window-has-focus-win32-api))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [WM_INITMENUPOPUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This is sent when a menu is about to be shown, so you can do whatever checks are necessary and enable/disable menu items appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I placed this in my resource.h file:

`#define WM_INITMENUPOPUP      0x0117`

... and the following code block inside my main window callback function (`LRESULT CALLBACK mainWndProc`) -- alongside WM_CREATE, WM_PAINT, etc.:

`if(GetFocus() != hWndTextbox)
{
 MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
 mii.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
 GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_EDIT_PASTE, FALSE, &mii);
 mii.fState ^= MFS_DISABLED;
 SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_EDIT_PASTE, FALSE, &mii);
}`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to disable the menu when the edit control does not have focus/lost focus?

In your WndProc the Edit control sends notifications in the form of a WM_COMMAND, the two that would interest you are:
EN_KILLFOCUS - when the control lost keyboard focus
EN_SETFOCUS - when the control gains keyboard focus.