# Need to know windows API to get a callback when my application is activated

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a wxWidgets windows application, I am launching annother application upon click a certain button on
my appication, This new launched application behaves like to modal window and my application is sent back, But
when user use Alt+Tab or click my appliction icon, My application comes to front, whereas child application 
which is already opened should have been shown

I figured how to bring an application to front, Now i would like to know if i can set a callback to parent application
which will be called whenever application is activated (either through Alt+Tab or task bar icon or any other way), 
So i can bring my child application to front at this time.Is there a windwos API for this?

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow` ?

Comment: Please ask about the problem you are trying to solve, not your proposed solution. See the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

[WM_ACTIVATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-activate)

> Sent to both the window being activated and the window being
>   deactivated. If the windows use the same input queue, the message is
>   sent synchronously, first to the window procedure of the top-level
>   window being deactivated, then to the window procedure of the
>   top-level window being activated. If the windows use different input
>   queues, the message is sent asynchronously, so the window is activated
>   immediately.

```
case WM_ACTIVATE: 
{ 
     // test if window is being activated 
     if(LOWORD(wParam)!=WA_INACTIVE) 
     { 
          // application is being activated 
     } 
     else 
     { 
          // application is being deactivated 
     } 
} 
break;
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use a hook to monitor whether the window is switched, you can refer to this link.

[Capture switch window event (window focus) (Alt+TAB)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c04e343f-f2e7-469a-8a54-48ca84f78c28/capture-switch-window-event-window-focus-alttab?forum=clr)

Comment: How to register for this message?

Comment: @StraightCirle It can be placed directly in the callback function of the parent application.

Comment: Sorry for the naive question here, I am new to windows API. So what is the api and register for WM_ACTIVE event? I tried with SetWinEventHook() but was not successful

Comment: @StraightCirle You don't need to use `SetWinEventHook()` or register for WM_ACTIVE event.  All you need to do is to add `WM_ACTIVATE`  message in WndProc , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7301529/11128312).